Can't connect to router/internet via ethernet
My WiFi is working but is extremely slow.
I'm trying to connect to the internet/router via Ethernet.
ip addr gives me:
enp0s7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether d0:50:99:91:6c:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:fe91:6cec/64 scope link tentative proto kernel_ll 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

But if I'm trying to sudo ifup enp0s7 output is:
dhcpcd-10.0.8 starting
DUID 00:01:00:01:2e:c7:cc:ea:d0:50:99:91:6c:ec
Dropped protocol specifier '.link' from 'enp0s7.link'. Using 'enp0s7' (ifindex=2).
enp0s7: waiting for carrier
timed out
dhcpcd exited
ifup: failed to bring up enp0s7

So I don't know how to go on from here. I tried various settings in Netplan without success.
What is possibly wrong?
I'm on Ubuntu Studio 24.10.

It looks like the NIC is not detecting the cable. Check the link light on your device and switch to see if both are connected and working.
Change interface state to up: sudo ip link set enp0s7 up
If both link lights are up, the interface is up, then I would check that there is a DHCP server available to get an address  from

Well thanks, but still not working.
I run a locally Docker for local Whisper-transcription. Is that a problem like local Ip addresses?
